# How to catch when component is Hidden?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to know when Hidden works. I have a two component, categories and news.

When screen resolution is a xsUp i want to show boths. When categories is visible news component paddingLeft = categiries.Width, But xsDown i want to hide categories grid and news component paddingLeft make to 0.

This is how it works.

```
 render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    let news = this.props.news.map((item, index) =>{
        return (
        <Zoom in={true} timeout={500}>
          <Grid item lg={3} xs={12} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} key={item.uid} spacing={16}>
            <Paper elevation={0} className={classes.paper}>
              <RecipeReviewCard info={item} />
            </Paper>
           </Grid>
        </Zoom>
  )
});

return (
  <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container className={classes.root}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Grid
              container
              spacing={16}
              className={classes.demo}
              alignItems={this.state.alignItems}
              direction={this.state.direction}
              justify={this.state.justify}
            >
            <Hidden xsDown>
              <Grid 
              item 
              lg={2} 
              md={4} 
              style={{
                width: 270, 
                maxWidth: 280, 
                minWidth: 270, 
                position: 'absolute', 
                height: '100%', 
                zIndex: 1
              }}>
                <Categories />
              </Grid>
            </Hidden>
              <Grid container item lg={12} md={12} spacing={16} style={{paddingLeft: 300, zIndex: 0}}
              >
                {news}
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
      </Grid>
  </div>
  ); 
}
```

[image: This is a full screen.]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution simple solution myself. I send my function for Categories component, And when Component didMounted or willUnmounted I send Boolean what happend.

Something like this:
Categories.js

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  console.log('CREATED');
  this.props.showFull(false);
};

componentWillUnmount = () => {
  this.props.showFull(true);
}
```

Main.js

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      direction: 'row',
      justify: 'flex-start',
      alignItems: 'stretch',
      hidden: true
    }
  }

  updateState = (ok) => {
    this.setState({
      hidden: ok,
    });
    console.log('updated ' + ' ' + ok);
  }


    return (
  <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container className={classes.root}>
            <Grid
              container
              spacing={16}
              className={classes.demo}
              alignItems={this.state.alignItems}
              direction={this.state.direction}
              justify={this.state.justify}
            >
            <Hidden xsDown>
              <Grid 
              item 
              lg={2} 
              md={4} 
              style={{
                width: '100%', 
                maxWidth: 280, 
                minWidth: 0, 
                position: 'fixed', 
                height: '100%', 
                zIndex: 1,
              }}>
                <Categories showFull={this.updateState} />
              </Grid>
            </Hidden>
              <Grid container item lg={12} md={12} spacing={16} 
                style={{paddingLeft: this.state.hidden ? 0 : 300, zIndex: 3}}
              >
                {news}
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
      </Grid>
  </div>
  );
```